# margins and alignment in input element in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am having trouble getting an input element and a button to align correctly. This is what it looks like:

[image: Notice the bottom alignment of button and input]

This comes from the following code:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="offset1 span6">
          <input type="text" class="l_input" placeholder="enter a city"></input>
     </div>
     <div class="span3"> 
          <button class="l_button btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want the input height to be the same as the button, which is not the case currently. I assume this is because of margins/padding, so I tried to set them to 0 px in my css: but it has no impact.

```
.l_input {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 }
```

What do I need to do to get the height of the input to be aligned with the height of the search button?

Comment: try with !important. Why </textarea>?

Comment: Something wrong here: `<input type="text" class="l_input" placeholder="enter a city"></textarea>`. Close tag </textarea>

Comment: thanks for pointing out the </textarea> - that is a typo, I will edit the question

Comment: Add your own CSS after bootstrap's. Use the web inspector to test, add the style to the element.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost right, but the margins and padding are in the other element. Try:

```
.l_input,
.l_button {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/j8G6n/)